# Protractor - Test is failed when element is not visible and doesn't perform the "else" condition

Tags: javascript, automation, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've tried to run a flow with "if/else statement" that depend on if some element is visible or not.

But in the case this element is not visible it doesn't run into the "else condition" and all the test case is failed.

Please your help! thanks.

**The test case:**

```
   it('New Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal', function () {
   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.binding("buttonText"))), 30000);
    element(by.binding("buttonText")).click();

            var mainWindow;
            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(
                function(handles) {
                    mainWindow = handles[0]; //at this point there should be only 1 window
                }
            );

            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {    
               handles.forEach(function(handle) {
                 if (handle !== mainWindow) {
                    browser.switchTo().window(handle)
                    var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));
                    element.all(by.id('loadLogin')).then(function(){ 
                        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');
                        browser.sleep(10000); 

                    loadLogin.isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
                          if (result === true) {
                                loadLogin.click();
                                browser.driver.sleep(3000);
                                element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
                                element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("pass");
                                browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                                element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
                                browser.driver.sleep(5000);
                                element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
                                browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                                console.log("-=-=- first condition - I'm not logged-in -=-=-");
                            } else {
                                 browser.driver.sleep(3000);
                                 element(by.id("login_email")).clear();
                                 browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                                 element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("username");
                                 element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("pass");
                                 browser.driver.sleep(1000);
                                 element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
                                 browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                                 element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
                                 browser.driver.sleep(10000);
                                 console.log("-=-=- second condition - I'm already logged-in -=-=-")
                            }
                        });
                    });
                 }
            });
        });

            browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
            });

});
```

**The error: [edited]**

```
 New Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal - fail
Error occurred in loadLogin.isDisplayed: { [NoSuchElementError: No element found
 using locator: By.id("loadLogin")]
  code: 7,
  state: 'no such element',
  message: 'No element found using locator: By.id("loadLogin")',
  name: 'NoSuchElementError',
  stack: 'NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("loadLogin")
\n    at new bot.Error (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pr
otractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\atoms\\error.js:113:18)\n    at
 C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\lib\\element.
js:706:15\n    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\\Users\\id
an\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webd
river\\lib\\webdriver\\promise.js:1877:20)\n    at [object Object].promise.Callb
ack_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modul
es\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\webdriver\\promise.js:246
4:25)\n    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\
\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\
webdriver\\promise.js:563:12)\n    at Array.forEach (native)\n    at Object.goog
.array.forEach (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor
\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\goog\\array\\array.js:203:43)\n    at [
object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\np
m\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\webdriver\\p
romise.js:552:16)\n    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppD
ata\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\l
ib\\goog\\async\\run.js:125:21)\n    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)\nE
rror\n    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\\Users\\idan\\A
ppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\lib\\element.js:403:21)\n    at
[object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (C:\\Users\\idan\\App
Data\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\lib\\element.js:76:19)\n    at [ob
ject Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppDat
a\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\lib\\element.js:733:11)\n    at c:\\a
utomation\\tests\\paymentsNewClient.js:71:39\n    at [object Object].promise.Con
trolFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\prot
ractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\webdriver\\promise.js:1877:20)\n
   at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\\Users\\idan
\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdri
ver\\lib\\webdriver\\promise.js:2464:25)\n    at [object Object].promise.Promise
.notify_ (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node
_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\webdriver\\promise.js:563:12)\n    at Array.f
orEach (native)\n    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roa
ming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\goog
\\array\\array.js:203:43)\n    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:
\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\se
lenium-webdriver\\lib\\webdriver\\promise.js:552:16)' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says that `loadLogin` element is not found. It doesn't say its not visible.

```
 NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("loadLogin")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("loadLogin")
```

It looks like you intend to interact with `loadLogin` element after you switch the new window, but it also appears that you are trying to find the element `loadLogin` before you switch to the window. Check the code below in the beginning of your test. Perhaps you need to switch to the window where `loadLogin` element is present and then look for it.

```
 it('New Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment by PayPal', function () {
        var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));
         browser.sleep(2000);
```

#### Edit 1

Its possible that some exception is thrown when the element is not visible and thats why you are never hitting the else condition. Perhaps add something like this,

```
loadLogin.isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
      //keep your code here
   }, function(err) {
       console.log('Error occurred in loadLogin.isDisplayed:', err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks again, but it doesn't work.
I've updated my post as well.
Please your help! @nilesh

Comment: Are you sure that loadLogin is in mainWindow? If it is NOT then you need to move this code AFTER you switch to handle (Pop up) -> var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));

Comment: Yes, I'm sure (please check out the updated code). it works fine with the "IF" condition, but in the "ELSE" condition in case this element is not visible it doesn't run into the "ELSE" statement and the test is failed.
Do you have any idea why it works only for the "IF" condition when the element is visible? @nilesh

Comment: I added one possibility and edited the answer. Please try it out  and report back

Comment: Done! I've added the error for you and hope you can help to find a solution for my problem, thanks a lot for everything! @nilesh

Comment: Well finally I've found a soloution for this based on your advice to print the error.. "isDisplayed() would check if an element is visible or not, but you need to check whether an element is present in DOM or not, use isElementPresent() or isPresent():"
And now it works! Thanks!